# What is the use of __threshold__ in Python?

Tags: python

I was going through some Python automation scripts and I saw the new (for me) keyword of  `___threshold__ = 0.6`. What it indicate? What it is used for?

Comment: Note that it's not a *keyword* in the meaning that's common in programming - keywords would be `return`, `def`, `for`, `in`, `not`, etc. - everything that's special-cased in the grammar and the implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There are only three hits for `python "__threshold__"` in Google](http://www.google.ca/search?q=python+%22__threshold__%22). This doesn't have any special meaning in Python, it's just an identifier someone chose to use. `__this_format__` is only supposed to be used by built-in names, to prevent confusion like this.